# TWA Browser URL Not hiding

Tags: deep-linking, twa

I am building up a TWA, i followed all tutorials online BUT cannot hide the upper url bar of chrome :(
the asset link file is here
https://www.thept.it/.well-known/assetlinks.json

I verificated the file with this tool https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://www.thept.it&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls

App is located here
https://www.thept.it/app

and this is the twa manifest

```
def twaManifest = [
            applicationId: 'it.thept',
        hostName: 'www.thept.it', // The domain being opened in the TWA.
        launchUrl: '/app', // The start path for the TWA. Must be relative to the domain.
        name: 'ThePT', // The name shown on the Android Launcher.
        themeColor: '#FF6628', // The color used for the status bar.
        navigationColor: '#ffffff', // The color used for the navigation bar.
        backgroundColor: '#FF6628', // The color used for the splash screen background.
        enableNotifications: false, // Set to true to enable notification delegation.
    // Add shortcuts for your app here. Every shortcut must include the following fields:
    // - name: String that will show up in the shortcut.
    // - short_name: Shorter string used if |name| is too long.
    // - url: Absolute path of the URL to launch the app with (e.g '/create').
    // - icon: Name of the resource in the drawable folder to use as an icon.
    shortcuts: [
        // Insert shortcuts here, for example:
    ],
    // The duration of fade out animation in milliseconds to be played when removing splash screen.
    splashScreenFadeOutDuration: 300
]
```

The error is

**W chromium: [WARNING:digital_asset_links_handler.cc(115)] Statement failure matching package.**

But the package name is it.thept.it.thept according to  Asset Links Tool

May you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, in build.gradle REMOVE

**//applicationIdSuffix = twaManifest.applicationId**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            //applicationIdSuffix = twaManifest.applicationId <------ this one
            versionNameSuffix = twaManifest.name
        }
    }
```